# Legal questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

On the main trilogy, there's a very consistent hard line drawn against amateur legal advice.

If you want to have the same policy here, you should vote to close:

[Is it possible to have GPL software in the Mac App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/gpl-software-in-mac-app-store)

Comment: Hm, good point. At the very least we should make it clear that the answers do NOT constitute legal advice.

Answer (score 8):

To me, it depends how much **danger** there is in such advice.

Like, medical advice here would be a bad idea because if someone gave you bad medical advice, *you could die*.

I am not sure that particular question holds any danger for anyone of any consequence, and the information it provides is at least useful as a starting point for research.

That said, if you saw a user providing *bad* or *careless* legal advice, that is -- more than simple basic pointers for research with the disclaimer that "hey, I'm no lawyer, I'm just a user like you, but here's what I know" -- then it's fair to vote that down or flag it.